# Setting a custom XOM EntityResolver

Tags: java, xom, entityresolver

I need to not validate against a doctype, so I'd like to set a custom `EntityResolver` that accepts everything. I'm getting data back from tagsoup, so I know my data is well-formed and correct.

Furthermore, I need to rapidly hit a number of documents, so when I do this with the default `EntityResolver`, I get `503` from `w3.org`.

How, then, can I use a XOM builder with a custom entity resolver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom XMLReader.

```
XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
reader.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver(){...});
Builder builder = new Builder( reader );
```